# Crontab isn't working with simple bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create a cron job to run a bash script. The bash script will basically check my file (`ip.address.txt`), find my public ip address, then check `ip.address.txt` again and compare the two. If they are different, my IP has changed and I should get a notification via email.

The script works manually, however, when attempting to add to a cron job, I then get an email saying that `Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently`. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3. I am attempting to do my first cron job using the command `crontab -e`". At the end of the file (everything about has been commented out), I have :

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * * /home/jj/Desktop/IP/publicIP.sh
```

This is a standalone desktop, and trying to do a user cron job. Thank you for your help on understanding more on cron jobs. I will also post bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Give crontab a path to follow according to what i have read ?????
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/jj/Desktop/IP/


#Get last saved IP address
ip1=$( cat /home/jj/Desktop/IP/ip.address.txt )

#This is the command to see public IP address
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > ip.address.txt

#This is the updated IP adress currently in use
ip2=$( cat /home/jj/Desktop/IP/ip.address.txt )

#Check to see if it is the same IP
    if [ $ip1 != $ip2 ]; then

#If the IP is different, the IP has changed. Notify me via email
    cat /home/jj/Desktop/IP/ip.address.txt | mail -s "IP Address" user@gmail.com

#EOF
fi
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
> ip.address.txt
```

with

```
> /home/jj/Desktop/IP/ip.address.txt
```

Comment: wow. I can't believe I missed that. I read about how the paths have to be completely written out and yet I still missed one. LOL I feel dumb. Thanks. And thanks for the editing tips.

Comment: Thats what variables are for ^^